# Solve the following simultaneous linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

> Solve:
> $a+b=4$, $a+c=3$, $b+d=3$, $c+d=2$

I tried and tried, but I could not find a solution for $a,b,c,$ and $d$.

But am I right to say, as there are $4$ variables and $4$ equations, this simultaneous linear equation can be solved?

If possible, help me solve this equations, thanks!

Comment: No. $a+b+c+d=17$, $a+b+c+d=42$, $a+b+c+d=-\pi$, $a+b+c+d=\sqrt2$ has four variables and four equations, but obviously has no solutions.

Comment: But your system has lots of solutions. See what happens, for example, if $a=1$.

Comment: "I tried and tried" - Can we see your attempts please? That way we can find your mistakes and know where to help you.

Comment: Hint: Write your system using a matrix.

Comment: Subtract the second equation from the first, and the fourth from the third. What do you observe?

Comment: both yield $b-c=1$

Comment: @ K.defaoite  i added each equation with equation and subtracted equation from result, and repeated many times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show what you tried so I can't say what your difficulty might be.
Your equations are: $a+b=4$ , $a+c=3$, $b+d=3$, $c+d=2$.

Whether or not "4 equations in four unknowns" has a solution depends upon whether or not the equations are "independent".

From $a+b=4$,  $b=4-a$.

So now we have  3 equations,
$a+ c= 3, 4- a+ d= 3$ so $a- d= 1$, and $c+ d= 2$ in three unknowns.

From $a+ c= 3$, $c= 3- a$.

So now we have two equations,
$a- d= 1$, and $3-a+ d= 2$ so $a- d= 1$.

Those are the same equation so the equations are NOT independent and there is no unique solution.

There are, rather, an infinite number of solutions.
From $a- d= 1$, $d= a- 1$.  We already have $c= 3- a$ and $b= 4- a$.  Given any value for $a$, $b= 4- a$, $c= 3- a$, and $d= a- 1$ is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you only have $3$ linear equations as: Subtracting first and second equation gives $b-c=1$ and so does subtracting the third and fourth equations. If we are given the first three equations (say) then the fourth equation is something that has to be true always, i.e. the last equation is dependent on the first three equations.